# jQuery Operation run One-time

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to run this function below only one-time? I mean if 'level' upper than -1, then the levelbar changing as looping according to this value. But I want to run '.progress-bar-fill' function one time. if the value upper than -1.

```
$(".progress-bar-fill").delay(1000).queue(function () {
    $(this).css('width', '100%')
});
```

**String**

> level

-

```
function callback_activityLevel(level) { 
    $("#level").html(level);

    if(level == -1) {
        $("#levelbar").css("width",  "0px");
    } else {
        var kontrol = 1;
        $("#levelbar").css("width", (level * 2)+ "px");
        if ( kontrol == 1 ) {
            $(".progress-bar-fill").delay(1000).queue(function () {
                $(this).css('width', '100%')
            });  
        }
    }
}
```

This an audio recorder scripting. Level Bar is changes according to voice' level.

Comment: You can keep track using a global variable, say, flag=true. Once executed, change that flag value to false. Check for flag before executing function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean. Set it once and check all the time. This example code executes the `// Rest of your function` part of your function once.

```
var wasCalled = false;

function doSomething() {
    if (wasCalled) {
        return;
    }
    wasCalled = true;
    // Rest of your function
}
```